Mixing functionals in TD-DFT opt
I work with copper complexes containing at least 100 atoms (including a single Cu, nitrogens, carbons, and hydrogens). According to Grimme's paper, the benchmark level for geometry optimization is PBE0-D4/def2TZVP. However, my system is too large for this level, so I use the other option he suggested, namely, (m)GGA with a TZ basis set. The literature adviced TPSS, so I chose it.
My studies also involve a TD-DFT component, which includes, among other things, the computation of intersystem crossing rates. For this purpose, ORCA requires Hessians. The problem arises because the best reproduction of the experimental spectra was achieved with PBE0. Using PBE0 to optimize my system in the S1 and T1 states and subsequently obtain .hess files is computationally demanding for my HPC resources. Moreover, unlike Gaussian, ORCA does not allow reading excitations from a checkpoint file, so I cannot reoptimize in TPSS without recalculating excitations. This means the S1 and T1 states obtained by TPSS would be considered.
What should I do now?

My guess is that it may be better to reduce the basis set of non-metal atoms to def2-SVP, than to change the functional to TPSS. TDDFT excitation energies tend to be less sensitive to the basis set size of non-metal atoms, than to the ratio of HF exchange.

@wzkchem5 so PBE0/def2SVP+def2TZVP for all?

Yes, it's worth to try this

Hi, @wzkchem5 . Thanks for the suggestion. I've decided to usePBE0+D4/def2-SVP(H,C,N) and def2-TZVP(Cu) along with def2/J and GCP(DFT/SVP) in CPCM(water) for entire study. I believe that switching to def2-TZVP for excited states energies, and their optimization with the mixed basis set would not yield actual states predicted by previous step.

You have run into the eternal conundrum of quantum chemistry I'm afraid, so no magic bullet. That being said, there are definitely some things I would try:
Reduce your basis set
I would second the opinion of wzkchem5 that keeping the hybrid functional is more important here than the basis set size. For the metal, triple zeta makes sense. For everything else, I would reduce to double zeta. For the prediction of electronic properties of organometallic complexes, it's still fairly common to use B3LYP with LANL2DZ on the metal (with ECPs) and 6-31+G** on everything else, which I think must go back to Yang et al. from 2009. I don't think you need to stick to that exact choice of functional/basis set, but something of equivalent size from the def2 family would make sense.
Because the metal-ligand bonding is often quite long range, it's probably a good idea to keep the diffuse functions. For the organic atoms, either ma-def2-SVP or def2-SVPD would be a good starting point. For the metal, def2-TZVP is probably fine. Make sure to benchmark your results against some higher order calculation or experimental data before committing of course.
Reduce your molecule
Hard to say for sure without knowing the structure, but you may be able to remove parts of the molecule without affecting the results. Methyls, tert-butyl groups and long alkyl chains often have little impact on the excited states, so can be removed (replaced with H). The major exception is if the alkyl group is responsible for forcing a particular molecular geometry (if sterics are important essentially), in which case the change in geometry can drastically impact the electronic states.
Try accelerated DFT
Orca has support for quite a lot of accelerating approximations that you might be able to take advantage of. Many of them are grouped under the umbrella term 'resolution of the identity' (or sometimes 'density fitting'), and they can result in big speed improvements under the right circumstances. Unfortunately (in a way), RIJCOSX is turned on automatically for hybrid functionals from Orca 5 onwards, so unless you've turned it off you're already benefiting from this speed boost. Might be worth investigating in case there's anything else you can exploit however. Have a look in the manual for RI-DFT.

But I would prefer to stick with TPSS/TPSSh geometries and PBE0 excitations.

Ok, you can do this if you want (although I wouldn't recommend it). Just run the optimisation first (with TPSS) and then subsequently do the excited states on the already optimised geometry with PBE0.

I am generally Gaussian user. Right now turned to ORCA because of TD-DFT capabilities. Choosing PBE0 to generate spectra, and rerunning with TPSS their optimization probably would still bring me to the TPSS excited state geometry, so different from the actual one predicted by PBE0 absorption?

Hi, @leeman . Thanks for the suggestion. I've decided to usePBE0+D4/def2-SVP(H,C,N) and def2-TZVP(Cu) along with def2/J and GCP(DFT/SVP) in CPCM(water) for entire study. I believe that switching to def2-TZVP for excited states energies, and their optimization with the mixed basis set would not yield actual states predicted by previous step.

Hi @farmaceut, In regards to your first question, yes you are correct that calculating the spectra first with PBE0 will have no bearing on the TPSS optimisation. What I was suggesting was you could do the TPSS optimisation first and then the spectra with PBE0. In regards to your second question, yes this makes sense to me (although I don't know what GCP is). I would lean towards ma-def2-SVP instead of def2-SVP but that's your choice of course.

Though I need to optimise excited states also; doing this with TPSS would lead to other ES than predicted by PBE0. That's why I believe mixing functionals isn't the wisest idea. If I only need absorption, then probably would be fine. GCP is a geometric counterpoise scheme, to avoid BSSE - probably wise using along with D4 and small def2SVP basis (that's why I pick SVP instead of TZVP).

Fair enough, best of luck with the results. If the answer was useful please remember to mark it as accepted.
